# Count the number of fields that are not empty in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of users where they can send messages to other users (up to four) and the ID of the message they sent is in their user row.

```
Name    | Email       | Msg1 | Msg2 | Msg3 | Msg4
--------+-------------+------+------+------+-----
Pez     | me@me.com   |  1   |  55  |  42  |  5 
Steve   | fake@me.com |  0   |   0  |   0  |  0 
Leon    | josh@me.com |  3   |   0  |   3  |  5
```

How in a MySQL query can I get the amount of those message rows that are not empty or not equal to 0, allowing me to order by that? So it would return

```
Pez   | 4 Mesasges
Leon  | 3 Messages
Steve | 0 Messages
```

Im my mind something like:

```
order by count(!empty(msg1)+!empty(msg2)+!empty(msg3)+!empty(msg4))
```

Comment: May I ask how you got the layout like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [normalized tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) it could be as simple as

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM messages WHERE userid=47
```

But with your schema try something like

```
SELECT
  name,
  (msg1<>0) + (msg2<>0) + (msg3<>0) + (msg4<>0) as cMessages
FROM
  foo
```

edit: Vincent Ramdhanie's answer using [if()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) doesn't rely on MySQL's behaviour to use 0 as false and 1 as true as result of a comparison. I would prefer that.

Answer (score 2):

```
 select 
     if(msg1 = 0, 0, 1) +
     if(msg2 = 0, 0, 1) +
     if(msg3 = 0, 0, 1) +
     if(msg4 = 0, 0, 1) as NumMsg,Name
 from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to [normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as follows:

```
Table users:    (user_id, name, email)
Table messages: (user_id, msg_number, msg_code)
```

The `users` table would have `user_id` as a primary key, while the `messages` table would have a composite primary key on `(user_id, msg_number)`. The `msg_number` field would represent the 1-4 message number (the number you represented in your column names).

The composite primary key would guarantee that each user can only have one message for each `msg_number`. You may also want to create a [check constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_Constraint) so that `msg_number` is always <= 4. Finally you may want to define `user_id` in the `messages` table as a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to the `users` table.

Note that if a user did not send a message, you should not have a row in the messages table with `msg_code` = 0. Instead, you should simply omit the row.

With normalized tables, counting the number of messages for each user would be as easy as:

```
SELECT    u.name, COUNT(m.msg_number) as num_of_messages
FROM      users u
JOIN      messages m ON (m.user_id = u.user_id)
GROUP BY  u.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said the right way to solve the problem is to normalize your database.

You can get the counts from the current schema - but its a bit messy:

```
SELECT name, (SIGN(msg1)+SIGN(msg2)+SIGN(msg3)+SIGN(msg4))
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY (SIGN(msg1)+SIGN(msg2)+SIGN(msg3)+SIGN(msg4)) DESC;
```

C.